# iOS 16 lock screen - calendar widget

Tags: ios, calendar, widgets

Since I upgraded my iPhone XS to iOS 16 I added a calendar widget on my lockscreen to show the next events of my day.

As shown on the screenshots below, the widget does not show the all-day event (neither for the current day or the next day). Is there a way to force the display of all day events on the widget ?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only means to show upcoming events including all-day events is to use a third party widget, e.g., [Widgy](https://apps.apple.com/de/app/widgy-widgets/id1524540481).

This is the JSON for a rectangular lock screen widget  using Widgy:

```
{"0":17,"p2":"","q2":"","1":[{"z":"1","d":{"a":[{"a":1200,"b":1031}],"b":0},"f":"uicol_white-100","66":[{"5":"Agenda (Chronological)","6":"Calendar #1 - Title"}],"d0":2,"b":{"b":0,"a":[{"a":400,"b":1031}]},"t":{"a":[{"a":0,"b":1031}],"b":0},"e":{"b":0,"a":[{"a":800,"b":1031}]},"c":{"a":[{"a":5.6843418860808015e-14,"b":1031}],"b":0}},{"d0":3,"d":{"b":0,"a":[{"a":400,"b":1035}]},"t":{"a":[{"a":0,"b":1035}],"b":0},"66":[{"5":"Agenda (Chronological)","6":"Calendar #1 - Start Date"},{"6":"Text","25":" ","5":"Custom Text"},{"5":"Agenda (Chronological)","6":"Calendar #1 - Start Time"}],"f":"uicol_white-100","z":"1","c":{"a":[{"b":1035,"a":5.6843418860808015e-14}],"b":0},"b":{"a":[{"b":1035,"a":2.8421709430404007e-14}],"b":0},"e":{"b":0,"a":[{"a":800,"b":1035}]}},{"66":[{"5":"Agenda (Chronological)","6":"Calendar #2 - Title"}],"d0":4,"f":"uicol_white-100","b":{"a":[{"a":400,"b":1044}],"b":0},"c":{"a":[{"b":1044,"a":800}],"b":0},"t":{"a":[{"b":1044,"a":0}],"b":0},"d":{"a":[{"a":1200,"b":1044}],"b":0},"z":"1","e":{"a":[{"a":800,"b":1044}],"b":0}},{"d0":5,"b":{"b":0,"a":[{"a":2.8421709430404007e-14,"b":1046}]},"f":"uicol_white-100","66":[{"5":"Agenda (Chronological)","6":"Calendar #2 - Start Date"},{"5":"Custom Text","25":" \n","6":"Text"},{"6":"Calendar #2 - Start Time","5":"Agenda (Chronological)"}],"d":{"a":[{"a":400,"b":1046}],"b":0},"t":{"b":0,"a":[{"a":0,"b":1046}]},"e":{"a":[{"b":1046,"a":800}],"b":0},"z":"1","c":{"a":[{"b":1046,"a":800}],"b":0}},{"d":{"b":0,"a":[{"a":1600,"b":1052}]},"1":"Reload Widget","e":{"b":0,"a":[{"b":1052,"a":1600}]},"z":"11","t":{"a":[{"b":1052,"a":0}],"b":0},"2":"widgyMin:\/\/","d0":6}],"n2":"","o2":"","zzz":"","6":6,"m2":"","l2":"","5":"D.A.D.","20":false,"(0":"Last Quarter","a2":7,"21":false,"3":"Next Events 3","9":905}
```